# illigible jsp and html files

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have jsp and HTML files in my java EE project (I work with Eclipse)
My WEB-CONTENT file has been removed. I recovered it with Recuva.
I realized that JSTL and JDBC were damaged so I implemented them again, I do not have the same errors anymore.
But I do not understand why my code is illegible!

[image: This is the connection view page]

This jsp file is for authentification

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).